# VS2015/MVC: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

This is not a dupe of the one hundred other questions of the same title.

I am trying to get my MVC views to build along with my regular project build so that I can locate errors.  I've come across several solutions that say to set `MvcBuildViews` to true in the project file like so:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MvcBuildViews>true</MvcBuildViews>
</PropertyGroup>
```

When I do this and then build my project, I get this:

`It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.`

What am I doing wrong here?